# Need More Information on a Failed XHR CORS Request to Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, servlets, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have logs that show XHR requests constantly failing for some of my users, who seem to be using the same internet connection at a University. The failed XHR requests have `readyState` 4 and `status` 0. They are all reported with Chrome, but that could be coincidence. I cannot reproduce the error on my end, and other users do not seem to be having the problem.

The XHR request is a CORS request going to a Tomcat webapp, running on port 8080. The Tomcat instance shows no errors in catalina.out that match the failed requests in timing, and my suspicion is that the web request is being blocked before it gets there. I have this code to handle the CORS request and it has been working fine so far:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String origin = req.getHeader("origin");
    if (origin != null) resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

Is there any way for me to further diagnose the problem using information I can collect using javascript? Could it be a security policy blocking the port from that location? Any other advice on debugging the problem?

Comment: Your assessment of port 8080 being firewalled at that user's site seems reasonable.  I've never considered running a production server on 8080, can't you use port 80?

Comment: Yeah, it's a small-scale student project and I've never had trouble with 8080. I need a webserver as well, but I can probably set a proxy to a directory on the server.

Comment: Ok, I've switched over to port 80 using mod_proxy_ajp. I'll update in a bit whether the errors stopped.